# What is the proper way to nest a set of paper-radio-button(s) in a paper-listbox?

Tags: html, polymer

I am trying to nest a group of paper-radio-buttons (encapsulated by a paper-radio-group) inside of a paper listbox in order to get them to display on separate lines. What is the proper way to do this? My current implementation attempt looks like this:

```
<paper-listbox>
    <paper-radio-group>
       <paper-radio-button name="1">1</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="2">2</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="3">3</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="4">4</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="5">5</paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="6">6</paper-radio-button>
   </paper-radio-group>
</paper-listbox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display: block` on `paper-radio-button`:

```
paper-radio-button {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-radio-button {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <paper-listbox>
        <paper-radio-group>
          <paper-radio-button name="1">1</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="2">2</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="3">3</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="4">4</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="5">5</paper-radio-button>
        </paper-radio-group>
      </paper-listbox>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BQvbLm?editors=1010)